# Update Debian 6.0.10 to latest or at least patch

Tags: debian, update, debian-squeeze, upgrade, legacy

I have a old server that I need to patch. The server is running on Debian 6.0.10. However, apt-get update/upgrade does not work. I have a bunch of 404 not found. I suspect the version is too old and I can update with apt... What are my options here before building a new server and migrating my code and apps ?

Regards,

Comment: What is this server serving? It may be an opportune time to rebuild and reconfigure from scratch, integrating newer (or perhaps different) software...

Comment: As for now, it`s not in the picture to do that. When I go to a total refectory, I will drop the machine, build a new one to host containers. So It will be easier to update the softwares that I really rely on...

Answer (score 1):

First step: Alter your package sources to point to the [Debian Archives](https://www.debian.org/distrib/archive) and update to the latest packages available there.

From there, you should update further to version 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to patch the current packages then point my sources.list to the next version and upgrade without any issue up to version 8, where Varnish get from version 3.x.y to version 4.x.y. (This is where is failed - only for Varnish) since it`s ferry different. But this is another story.

So it did work fine.